# SQLite - Auto increment doesnt work as expected?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to create a table called `tasksTable` that has two columns - `taskName` and Its auto increment `taskID`.

This is the class with which I've created the database and implemented operations that manipulate the table described above -

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final int database_version = 1;
    ***public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE tasksTable(taskName TEXT, taskID INTEGER primary key AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL);"

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database created successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table created successfully");
    }


    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String taskName){

        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.TASK_NAME, taskName);

        SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database operations", "One row inserted");
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop) {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.TASK_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.TASK_ID};

        return SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that as soon as i am turning on the application, i get the following error -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.hw_3/com.android.hw_3.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: taskID (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT taskName, taskID FROM tasksTable

Maybe it has to be something about the way i implemented `putInformation`? I am not sure that this is how a new error is added, given the fact that there's this "implicit" column `taskID`.

Comment: If my answer seems helpful then please give an upvote. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: `taskID` (code
>   1): , while compiling: `SELECT` `taskName`, `taskID` FROM `tasksTable`

You `tasksTable` was not created properly.

**Update your `CREATE_QUERY` as below:**

```
public String CREATE_QUERY =  "CREATE TABLE tasksTable(taskName TEXT, taskID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);"
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: perfect copy of the above answer...!!

Comment: Can you please remove your sunglass and see again. hope you will find the difference. Thank you :)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM copypaste`  is  same as `select * from copypaste`...i hop U Knoww; ;`

Comment: it's called case sensitivity

Comment: I know brother. but can't you see the difference between "INTEGER primary key AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL" and "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" ????

Comment: not really i don't !! i wear sunglass at night..hop u understnd

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is not same as AUTOINCREMENT. Hope now you understand the difference. :)

Answer (score 0):

use this query for create table :-

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE tasksTable(taskName TEXT, taskID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE KEY `taskID` (`taskID`));"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  rename type from INT to INTEGER

Here is the supported type in [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

change your code to :

```
 public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE tasksTable(taskName TEXT, taskID INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);"
```

Comment: Should i say, you just updated your answer after copying from my post........... AUTO_INCREMENT to  AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: ooo sure u can say whatever u want...! for clarification i just remove the sunglass not looking your answer..!

Comment: don't take it personally... I was just joking about your sunglass.